# Button click in web application with ASP.NET and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I am new in csharp and asp.net, I am writing an web application with asp.net and csharp, anyway;
In my default.aspx I have button, if I click the button I want to open different page(e.g. asdfg.aspx). To do this I write this code in default.aspx:

```
 <asp:Button ID="button1" runat="server" Text="Click Button" OnClick="ButtonClick" />
```

in my default.aspx.cs I created this code segment:

```
public void ButtonClick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{


}
```

After that what can I do? Thanks

p.s.Sorry for my english.

Comment: dont forget to mark answer as accepted if it works for you ....

Comment: no you need to click on the right sign below the answer to accept it and need 15 rep to upvote the answer ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public void ButtonClick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("~/asdfg.aspx");

}
```

Just a notice: the handle shouldn't be a public method, it't very unusual to instantiate the Page class and call it from another class. So you can make it protected or private.

The tilda notation (prefix) "~" is special in ASP .Net. It means the new location is related to the application which can differ by the website root. An website can have multiple applications (ie, you can have the main site and another "subsite" called admin). If you would be inside the admin application ASP .Net knows how to build the new location related to admin and not to the root website.

Comment: Thanks I see that it was very easy :)

Comment: Sorry but if I write "Response.Redirect("~/asdfg.aspx"); what will I write in pageLoad code of asdfg.aspx.cs ? I mean after "Response.Redirect("~/asdfg.aspx"); it doesn't go to this page ( asdfg.aspx). On the other hand are there any tutorial about this problem ?

Comment: You can use Response.Redirect("/asdfg.aspx") or Response.Redirect("asdfg.aspx"). You don't need to write anything in asdfg.aspx Page_Load event. Check MSDN for Response.Redirect

Comment: Ok I solved, due to web.config, I didn't connect pages. I corrected web.config. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Response.Redirect(urlstring);
```

in the ButtonClick method

Answer (score 0):

```
public void ButtonClick(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{  
      Response.Redirect("~/asdfg.aspx");  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Use `Server.Transfer("url")` or `Response.Redirect("url")`

Response.Redirect simply sends a message down to the (HTTP 302) browser.

Server.Transfer happens without the browser knowing anything, the browser request a page, but the server returns the content of another.

```
public void ButtonClick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
response.Redirect("~/asdfg.aspx");

}
```